# If $f(0)=0$ and $\underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{lim} f(t)=0$, then is $f(t)$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $$ f: \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ a continuous function, such that:
$$f(0)=0 $$ $$ \underset{t \rightarrow + \infty}{lim} f(t)=0$$

I wonder, what could be said about this function? As it is continuous, I want to say that it is bounded, but the issues  get it that interval isn't a closed one, it's $[0; +\infty )$, thus I am unsure if I can say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bounded. Given the limit, there exists $x_0 > 0$ such that $|f(x)| \le M$ for $x > x_0$, so the function is bounded on $(x_0, + \infty)$. By continuity, $f(x)$ is also bounded on the compact interval $[0,x_0]$. And then it is bounded on the union of $(x_0, + \infty)$ and $[0,x_0]$.